# android phonegap skip main page at the second launch

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm developing an android mobile app with phonegap.
On the main menu I have 4 images and when a image is clicked, it redirects user to another page.
What I want is the app to remember what the user has chosen first time when he opened the app so when he lunches the app for the second time, the app should open directly to the page that he choosen first time.

My first page that i want to skip at the second lunch of the app looks like that:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="res/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img.imgnavbar").animate({
    opacity: 1.0,
  }, 800 );
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
      body{background-color:black; background-repeat:no-repeat; position:absolute;}
                  img.imgnavbar{height:auto; width:48%;   opacity: 0.0;}
      .menu{padding-top:55%;}  
                  img.shadow{height:auto; width:100%; bottom:0px; position:fixed; left:0%; z-index:-1;}
                  img.choose{height:auto; width:100%; top:0px; position:absolute; z-index:-1;}

                </style>
</head>
<body>
<div  align="center" class="menu">
<img  src='img/cosmote4.png' id="cosmote"  class="imgnavbar" value="1"/>
<img  src='img/germanos2.png' id="germanos" class="imgnavbar" value="2"/>
<img  src='img/zapp2.png' id="zapp"  class="imgnavbar" value="3"/>
<img  src='img/sunlight4.png' id="sunlight" class="imgnavbar" value="4"/>
</div>
<img  src='img/choose.png' id="choose" class="choose"/>
<img  src='img/shadow.png' id="shadow" class="shadow"/>


<script>
$("img.imgnavbar").click(function(){
                if (confirm('Are you sure you choose this company?')) {
                $("img.imgnavbar").animate({
    opacity: 0.0,
  }, 800 );

  switch ($(this).attr('src')) { 

        case "img/cosmote4.png":
            $("img.choose").animate({"top": "-=60%"}, "slow");
                                $("img.shadow").animate({"bottom": "-=100%"}, "slow");
                                                setInterval(function(){window.location.replace("cosmote.html");
},800);
            break; 

        case "img/germanos2.png":
            $("img.choose").animate({"top": "-=60%"}, "slow");
                                $("img.shadow").animate({"bottom": "-=100%"}, "slow");
                                                setInterval(function(){window.location.replace("germanos.html");
},800);
            break; 

        case "img/zapp2.png":
            $("img.choose").animate({"top": "-=60%"}, "slow");
                                $("img.shadow").animate({"bottom": "-=100%"}, "slow");
                                                setInterval(function(){window.location.replace("zapp.html");
},800);
            break;

        case "img/sunlight4.png":
            $("img.choose").animate({"top": "-=60%"}, "slow");
                                $("img.shadow").animate({"bottom": "-=100%"}, "slow");
                                                setInterval(function(){window.location.replace("sunlight.html");
},800);
            break; 
    }
}
else{}
});
</script>



</body>

</html>

Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the local storage in PG to save preferences.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

So when loading the chosen page save the information into the local storage.
When loading the main page do a javascript check towards the local storage to check if there is a existing value for this key, if there is, redirect accordingly if not then it is the first launch; do nothing.